# MYSQL view groupby

Tags: mysql

```
Below is the cutomerOrdersByName View: 
# Returns total for each order ordered from largest to smallest.

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS customerOrdersByName;

CREATE VIEW customerOrdersByName AS
    SELECT d.orderNumber
         , customerName
         , round(SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach),2) total
      FROM orderDetails d
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.orderNumber = d.orderNumber
INNER JOIN customers c ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
  GROUP BY customerName
  ORDER BY total DESC;
```

How do I modify the customerOrdersByName view so that it groups and orders the totals by customer name and then by total from highest to lowest?

Answer (score 1):

By modifying order by clause:

```
GROUP BY customerName
ORDER BY customerName asc, total DESC;
```

However, I do not get the order number in the select list. If you do not group by on it, you should also remove it from the select list.